# Print the count of even values at odd levels from a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I have a binary search tree and I need to print the total count of even values that are at odd levels.

I have an algorithm to do the traversal in order, but I don't know how to make it count the level of the tree to know if a given even value is at an odd level.

Inorder algorithm

```
void printInOrder(Node *root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        printInOrder(root->left);
        printf("%d ", root->key);
        printInOrder(root->right);
    }
```

(*the level count starts at zero where the root is*)
**Example 1:**

[BST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AE2kr.png)

*number of even keys that are at odd levels: **2***

Example 2:

[BST 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dieRr.png)

*number of even keys that are at odd levels: **6***

I'm really lost, any help is welcome.

Comment: You can traverse the tree in any order and get the job done. Forget about printing. Create a function that returns the sum of all of the even values, regardless of the level. Do not print. Just return the sum. Once you are done, deal with the levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the total count of even values that are at odd levels, you need to keep a global variable, that will store the count of even nodes.
You need to traverse the tree inOrder wise, and only traverse over the given level for odd nodes.
I am attaching the code snippet below. Print the variable `c` to get the required result.

```
int c=0; // Maintain a global variable to keep count
int printLevelOrder()
{
   int h = height(root);
  
   for(int i=1;i<=h;i++)   // i=1 -> level 0
   {
      if( (i-1)%2 != 0)   // level start from 0 and height from 1. traverse only for odd levels 
      {
          evenNode(root, i);
      }
    }
    
}

// fn to calculate the height of BST
int height(Node root)
{
    if(root == null)
      return 1;
     else
     {
         int lheight = height(root.left);
         int rheight = height(root.right);

          if(lheight > rheight)
             return lheight;
          else
             return rheight;

      }
}

// traversing at a given level
void evenNode(Node root, int level)
{
   if(root == null)
     return ;
   if(level ==1)
   {
      if(root.data %2 == 0)  // check if bode is even then increase counter.
           c++;
   }
   else if(level > 1)
   {
      evenNode(root.left , level -1);
      evenNode(root.right, level - 1);
   }
}
```

Comment: I made a few small changes and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this :

```
void printInOrder(Node *root, int level)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        if (level & 1) {
            // Do something at odd level only
        }
        printInOrder(root->left, level+1);
        printInOrder(root->right, level+1);
    }
}
```